# How to select 24 hours record in mysql each of one hour?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Input to the query is date and start time
and end time will be same as the start time
So i want the 24 hours record by the given time

For Example 
date=2016-08-11
Start time=06:30:00 AM

so the end time is also 06:30:00 AM
but the date should be changed to the 2016-08-12
dynamically and end time should be 06:30:00 AM
and the interval should be 1 hour

Expected Result

```
 Date          Starttime     Endtime
 2016-08-11    00:00:07      00:21:55
 2016-08-11    01:00:27      01:59:10
 2016-08-11    02:00:09      02:59:33
```

table structure as below

```
 Date_         Starttime     Endtime
'2016-08-11'   00:00:07      00:21:55
'2016-08-11'   01:00:27      01:29:32
'2016-08-11'   01:30:32      01:59:10
'2016-08-11'   02:00:09      02:29:49
'2016-08-11'   02:30:48      02:59:33
'2016-08-11'   03:30:31      03:59:13
'2016-08-11'   04:00:12      04:29:47
'2016-08-11'   04:30:46      04:59:40
'2016-08-11'   05:00:39      05:29:42
'2016-08-11'   05:30:41      05:59:24
'2016-08-11'   06:00:23      06:29:01
'2016-08-11'   06:30:00      06:59:33
'2016-08-11'   07:00:31      07:29:25
'2016-08-11'   07:30:24      07:59:57
'2016-08-11'   08:00:57      08:29:39
'2016-08-11'   08:30:38      08:59:58
'2016-08-11'   09:00:50      09:29:22
'2016-08-11'   09:30:14      09:59:17
'2016-08-11'   10:00:08      10:29:58
'2016-08-11'   10:30:48      10:59:57
'2016-08-11'   11:00:48      11:29:31
'2016-08-11'   11:30:26      11:59:32
'2016-08-11'   12:00:24      12:29:35
```

for any explation please comment

Comment: `end time will be same as the start time` eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you

```
SELECT date,MIN(Starttime),MAX(Endtime) FROM your_table 
  WHERE CONCAT(date,' ',Starttime) >= CONCAT(?,' ',?) 
   AND CONCAT(date,' ',Starttime) < CONCAT(DATE_ADD(?,INTERVAL 1 DAY),' ',?) 
  GROUP BY date,HOUR(Starttime)
```

Give your input for '?' like below.

```
SELECT date,MIN(Starttime),MAX(Endtime) FROM your_table 
  WHERE CONCAT(date,' ',Starttime) >= CONCAT('2016-08-11',' ','06:30:00') 
   AND CONCAT(date,' ',Starttime) < CONCAT(DATE_ADD('2016-08-11',INTERVAL 1 DAY),' 06:30:00') 
  GROUP BY date,HOUR(Starttime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert to timestamp and add 86400 which is equivalent to 1 day

```
  select * from table where  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Starttime`) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('datetimeStart') and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Endtime`) <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('datetimeStart')+86400
```